# Trying to return an address - gets cut off when returned

Tags: solidity, remix

I have these 3 functions in a contract I am writting. I am currently using https://remix.ethereum.org to help me debug/better understand what the code is doing.

When I call `GetPassedAddr(address _addr)` with say

```
0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c
```

I get back

```
0x8dfe2f44e8fa733c000000000000000000000000
```

It cuts the address in half, takes the second half and appends a bunch of 0's and then returns that value. It does this for any address I input.

Any ideas why?

```
function GetCallingAddr() public view returns(address) {
    return msg.sender;
}

function GetPassedAddr(address _addr) public view returns(address) {
    return _addr;
}

function GetAddrZero() public view returns(address) {
    return address(0);
}
```

SOLVED
My problem was that I was passing the in contract digits without quotes, therefore remix was interpreting that as an int/float and was cutting off the digits

Comment: Try with your address between quotes, "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c". I think javascript is interpreting your address as a number, and since javascript numbers have limited precision it loses the last digits.